# Variable returns wrong value in specific class

Tags: c#

I have Form1 and and two classes called 'Holder'(I set and hold value there) and 'MedApp' (where I try to get variable value but get wrong). When I access variable from Form1 then I get correct value.
I kept deleting my whole project code trying to find what causes the problem but coulnd find. When even left only few lines of code.. still same.

Form1:

```
  namespace TestApp
  {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    Holder m_Holder = new Holder();
    MedApp m_MedApp = new MedApp();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Holder.SetValue();
        m_MedApp.pShowValue();
        MessageBox.Show("Accesing from Form1 shows : " + m_Holder.LoggedIn.ToString());
    }
   }
  }
```

Holder: I set and hold variable here

```
namespace TestApp
{
class Holder
{
    public int m_isLogedIn = 0;
    public int LoggedIn
    {
        get { return m_isLogedIn; }
        set { m_isLogedIn = value; }
    }


    public void SetValue()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Setting value 1");
        LoggedIn = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("New value is : " + LoggedIn.ToString());
    }

}
}
```

MedApp: Where I get wrong value. (0 instead of 1)

```
 namespace TestApp
 {
  class MedApp
  {
      public Holder m_Holder = new Holder();

      public void pShowValue()
      {
          MessageBox.Show("!!! This should show value 1, but shows :  " + m_Holder.LoggedIn.ToString());
      }      
  }
 }
```

When I run code MessageBox from 'MedApp' class shows value 0. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LitKs.png (ss of MessageBox showing wrong value)
But when I Access same variable from Form1 I get value 1.

Comment: Because you have two different `Holder` instance. One having the value `1` and other has the default of `0`. You need to learn some basics.

Comment: Oh, I see it now! Just never read what 'public Holder m_Holder = new Holder();' does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `Holder` in your `MedApp` class. So this is a different one than the one in your `Form1` class.

Basically what you are doing is this:
- Create a `Holder` object from within your `Form1` class and set the value of `LoggedIn`
- On the click of a button create `MedApp` object which creates it's own `Holder` object, and try to read the value you have set on a completely different object.

Although they seem to have the same name, you will not end up with the same object instance. You may want to read up on [basic Class and Object documentation for C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If you want to see the same value from different places you will have to find a way to access the `Holder` object you have created in the Form1 class, i.e. by inserting it into the `pShowValue` procedure.

Change your `Form1` class to this;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_Holder.SetValue();
        m_MedApp.pShowValue(m_Holder); /* supply Holder object here */
        MessageBox.Show("Accesing from Form1 shows : " + m_Holder.LoggedIn.ToString());
    }
```

And int your MedApp class:

```
class MedApp
  {
      // Remove this
      //public Holder m_Holder = new Holder();

      public void pShowValue(Holder mHolder) /* Add parameter here */
      {
          MessageBox.Show("!!! This should show value 1, but shows :  " + mHolder.LoggedIn.ToString());
      }      
  }
```

There are of course other solutions like static variables.

Answer (score 0):

Huh? You have two different instances of `Holder`. They can't give you the same result. Either pass the instance to the particular class or create a static, global instance.

Answer (score 0):

`MedApp` holds an instance of your `Holder` class. When you set `m_Holder.SetValue();`, you are effectivley setting it on the instance which you hold inside your `Form1` class, and **NOT** inside your `MedApp` instance. If you wanted this to work, you'd have to expose some sort of way to set the `Holder` instance inside `MedApp` a value:

```
class MedApp
{
    public Holder m_Holder = new Holder();

    public void IncrementHolder()
    {
       ++m_Holder.LoggedIn;
    }

    public void pShowValue()
    {
       MessageBox.Show("!!! This should show value 1, but shows :  " + 
                       m_Holder.LoggedIn.ToString());
    }      
}
```

And then call it from your `Form1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_MedApp.IncrementHolder();
    m_MedApp.pShowValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different instances of Holder.
Try change to something like this:

```
Holder m_Holder = new Holder();
MedApp m_MedApp = new MedApp(m_Holder);
```

...

```
class MedApp
{
  Holder m_Holder;

  public MedApp(Holder holder) {
      m_Holder = holder;
  }

  public void pShowValue()
  {
      MessageBox.Show("!!! This should show value 1, but shows :  " +    m_Holder.LoggedIn.ToString());
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different instances of the class Holder. They hold different copies of the variable and thus they can have different values.

If you want to share the variable m_isTobLoggedIn between different instances of the Holder class you can make it static (and also I'd recommend to remove the public modifier as you're exposing this variable through the property LoggedIn):

```
static int m_isTobLoggedIn = 0;
```

Another approach would be to access the instance of the Holder class declared in one of those classes (Form1 and MedApp) from the other one instead of instantiating this class twice in different classes.

For example, you can put it in the MedApp class, expose via some public property and then access from the Form1 class.